# RAD Studio 10.2.3 Linux + Win32

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, c++builder

I am looking for a confirmation that I can build a cross-platform application for Windows 32-bit and Linux using RAD Studio 10.2.3.

I still cannot confirm how to implement this using FMX.

Comment: _"I am looking for a confirmation that I can build a crossplatform application for Windows 32 bits and Linux."_ You should be able to do so. What did you specify in your project options? _"I still cannot confirm how to implement this by FMX."_ I am not familiar with the _implement by FMX_ term, please be so kind and explain further about that.

Comment: You may consider the Open-Source Lazarus for Windows + Linux desktop apps. See https://www.lazarus-ide.org/index.php?page=downloads

Comment: Why is this tagged VCL and Firemonkey?

Comment: As the [tech specs](https://www.embarcadero.com/products/rad-studio/tech-spec) for Rio (10.3.1) don't mention Linux 32-bit and say that FMX for Linux 64 is available via third-party add-ins, it's pretty unlikely that 10.2.3 and FMX will support 32-bit Linux development.

Answer (score 9):

Currently in 10.2 Tokyo and later, there is built-in support for Linux, but only for server-side development, such as WebBroker applications:

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Linux_Application_Development

However, there is a third party offering cross-platform Linux GUI application development tools leveraging FMX:

https://www.fmxlinux.com